# LinearGradient with mask does not fill the whole area

Tags: ios, swiftui, geometryreader

I'm creating a line chart view, inspired by [this blog post](https://trailingclosure.com/recreating-the-strava-activity-graph/).

The lines are drawn with Path and the gradient with a LinearGradient and a mask, and they are in overlays on top of each other.

**My main issue is that, as you can see in the screenshot, the start of all the gradients have a slope, they seem to close too soon if the value is zero** (also the ends seem to be cut too early but it's not my main isssue). The starts also seem to begin too late if the value is > 0 (like the orange one).

[image: swiftui line chart]

**What I want is for the gradient to fully fill the parts where the red arrows are pointing (removing the slopes and the abrupt cuts).**

But I can't find a solution by just shuffling up the magic numbers. Besides, I'd prefer to understand what's happening rather than just poking around.

What am I doing wrong?

---

I've made a reproducible example, paste this is a ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var values: [Double] = [0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 6, 4, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
    @State var totalMaxnum: Double = 6
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    // some other view
                    
                    VStack {
                        VStack {
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                                .overlay(
                                    ZStack {
                                        Color.white.opacity(0.95)
                                        
                                        drawValuesLine(values: values, color: .blue)
                                    }
                                )
                                .overlay(
                                    ZStack {
                                        Color.clear
                                        
                                        drawValuesGradient(values: values, start: .orange, end: .red)
                                    }
                                )
                                .frame(width: proxy.size.width - 40, height: proxy.size.height / 4)
                            
                            // some other view
                        }
                        
                        // some other view
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func drawValuesLine(values: [Double], color: Color) -> some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            Path { p in
                let scale = (geo.size.height - 40) / CGFloat(totalMaxnum)
                var index: CGFloat = 0
                
                let y1: CGFloat = geo.size.height - 10 - (CGFloat(values[0]) * scale)
                let y = y1.isNaN ? 0 : y1
                p.move(to: CGPoint(x: 8, y: y))
                
                for _ in values {
                    if index != 0 {
                        let x1: CGFloat = 8 + ((geo.size.width - 16) / CGFloat(values.count)) * index
                        let x = x1.isNaN ? 0 : x1
                        let yy: CGFloat = geo.size.height - 10 - (CGFloat(values[Int(index)]) * scale)
                        let y = yy.isNaN ? 0 : yy
                        p.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
                    }
                    index += 1
                }
                
                
            }
            .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 3, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round, miterLimit: 80, dash: [], dashPhase: 0))
            .foregroundColor(color)
        }
    }
    
    func drawValuesGradient(values: [Double], start: Color, end: Color) -> some View {
        LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [start, end]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
            .padding(.bottom, 1)
            .opacity(0.8)
            .mask(
                GeometryReader { geo in
                    Path { p in
                        let scale = (geo.size.height - 40) / CGFloat(totalMaxnum)
                        var index: CGFloat = 0
                        
                        // Move to the starting point
                        let y1: CGFloat = geo.size.height - (CGFloat(values[Int(index)]) * scale)
                        let y = y1.isNaN ? 0 : y1
                        p.move(to: CGPoint(x: 8, y: y))
                        
                        // Draw the lines
                        for _ in values {
                            if index != 0 {
                                let x1: CGFloat = 8 + ((geo.size.width - 16) / CGFloat(values.count)) * index
                                let x = x1.isNaN ? 0 : x1
                                let yy: CGFloat = geo.size.height - 10 - (CGFloat(values[Int(index)]) * scale)
                                let y = yy.isNaN ? 0 : yy
                                p.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
                            }
                            index += 1
                        }
                        
                        // Close the subpath
                        let x1: CGFloat = 8 + ((geo.size.width - 16) / CGFloat(values.count)) * (index - 1)
                        let x = x1.isNaN ? 0 : x1
                        p.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: geo.size.height))
                        p.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 8, y: geo.size.height))
                        p.closeSubpath()
                    }
                }
            )
    }
}
```

You can see in the screenshot how the orange gradient doesn't properly fill all the area below the line:

[image]

Comment: Seems like this line: `p.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 8, y: geo.size.height))`. Try changing it to `p.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: geo.size.height))`.

Comment: @aheze Thanks. I also thought about that but it didn't fix it. Actually I think `p.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 8, y: geo.size.height))` should be `p.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 8, y: geo.size.height - (CGFloat(values[0]) * scale)))` since we're supposed to come back to the original point, but when I do that it draws a diagonal line from bottom right to top left...

Comment: Hmm ok. Can you make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), without stuff like `model.allvalues`?

Comment: @aheze I will try, sure

Comment: Thanks! It's much easier to debug when we can just copy-paste into Xcode.

Comment: @aheze I have added a simple example you can copy/paste in a ContentView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
let y1: CGFloat = geo.size.height - (CGFloat(values[Int(index)]) * scale)
```

`y1` becomes the height of the entire graph.

[image: Starting point of gradient, whose y is the graph's height, circled]

You need to subtract 10, because that's what you've been doing for your blue line and all the gradient's other points.

```
                              /// subtract 10
let y1: CGFloat = geo.size.height - 10 - (CGFloat(values[Int(index)]) * scale)
```

[image: Starting point of gradient, whose y is the graph's height minus 10 (exactly the place where the blue line starts), circled]

Comment: I could swear I already tried that. Well, looks like I didn't... Thanks a lot for spotting this issue and adding an explanation with a nice image, this is very cool.

Comment: @ButterflyBall np. Also you said "the ends seem to be cut too early," but it looks ok to me...